# Misplaced labels / wrong positional constraint in xcode

Tags: xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have 8 labels (let's call them a-h), that should be positioned under each other. Apart from the other constraints, i do that with:

```
a) top space to superview (3)
a) bottom space to b (22)
b) top space to a (22)
b) bottom space to c (22)
```

and so on...

The labels are positioned 22 apart from each other on the Y-axis.

This only works however, if

```
c) bottom space to d (-22) !!!
d) top space to c (-22) !!!
```

So for some reason the AutoLayout seems to want to place label d on the complete wrong position and i have to adjust to that by setting the constraint to -22 instead of 22. I can't see a reason why.

My other constraints for the labels are always:

```
- align center y to (the input element next to it)
- leading space to superview
```

Next to each label i always set up an input element (UITextField or UISwitch) that always have the following constraints:

```
- trailing space to superview
- width
- height
- align center y to (their respective label)
```

What might be happening here? Thanks :)
Note: If adjusting to the wrong position by -22 instead of 22, everything looks perfectly fine - i am just bothered by the -22.

EDIT: 2 of the 8 rows have both UISwitch as the input element next to the label. Both UISwitch's only have the `Trailing space to superview` and `align center y to (corresponding label)` constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the size inspector in the utilities pane, then double click the constraint, then tap on the drop down box after "first item", and select "reverse first and second item", you should be all set.